# What is an alternative to sorted() in this situation? Or can this be managed?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Considering the following dictionary...

```
d = {'ab': 3, 'aa': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'a': 1}

>>>sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True)[:2]
['b', 'ab']
```

Using sorted, the goal was to produce the keys associated with the two highest values. Here is where I am having trouble getting it to do what I want: When two values are tied, the key which appears first alphabetically should be chosen. So in this case what I actually want returned is ['b', 'aa'] since 'aa' and 'ab' both have the value of 3. The values of the dictionary will also always be positive if that helps.

Comment: Will the numbers always be positivE?

Comment: Yeah, I will add that to the original post.

Comment: I actually get the expected output from the code you gave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
>>> d = {'ab': 3, 'aa': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'a': 1}
>>> sorted(d, key=lambda x: (-d[x], x))
['b', 'aa', 'ab', 'c', 'a']
>>> sorted(d, key=lambda x: (-d[x], x))[:2]
['b', 'aa']
```

or

```
>>> sorted(d, key=lambda x: (-d[x], x.lower()))[:2]
['b', 'aa']
```

depending on how much you care about the case.

You could also take advantage of the fact that the sort is stable and do it in two passes:

```
>>> sorted(sorted(d), key=d.get, reverse=True)
['b', 'aa', 'ab', 'c', 'a']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'ab': 3, 'aa': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'a': 1}
print sorted(d, key = lambda x: (-d[x], x))[:2]
```

**Output**

```
['b', 'aa']
```

Since we return tuples as keys, comparisons will happen like mentioned [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types)

Comment: @mhlester You are correct, this will work with negatives as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
key=lambda x:(-d[x], x)
```

Edited for negative value

Comment: Won't work. OP wants to reverse sort on `d[x]` and non-reverse sort on `x`

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted(d, key=lambda dx: (-d[dx], d))[:2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind reshaping your data:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> d = {'ab': 3, 'aa': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'a': 1}
>>> sorted(d, key=lambda k:(d[k], k), reverse=True)
['b', 'ab', 'aa', 'c', 'a']
>>> cols = {}
>>> for k,v in d.items():
...     if v not in cols:
...         cols[v] = []
...     cols[v].append(k)
... 
>>> cols
{1: ['a'], 2: ['c'], 3: ['ab', 'aa'], 4: ['b']}
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([cols[k] for k in sorted(cols, reverse=True)]))
['b', 'ab', 'aa', 'c', 'a']
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([cols[k] for k in sorted(cols, reverse=True)]))[:2]
['b', 'ab']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't have a requirement to sort by key if the count is tied, then `Counter` is the correct data structure to solve this problem.

```
from collections import Counter
d = {'ab': 3, 'aa': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'a': 1}
cnt = Counter(d)
d.most_common(2)
```

Adding the requirement to sort by key means:

```
sorted(d.most_common(2), key=lambda k,v: (v,k))
```